# Rational functions on varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

To give a rational function $f$ in the function field $K(X)$ of a smooth projective curve $X$ is equivalent to giving a finite morphism $f:X\to \mathbb P^1$.

What is the precise analogue of this statement for higher-dimensional varieties?

I would guess that a rational function on a smooth projective variety gives rise to a rational morphism $X\dashrightarrow\mathbb P^1$ and that this is a morphism up to blowing-up $X$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is an integral scheme of finite type over a field $k$ ($k$-variety), there is a bijection
$$K(X)\simeq \{\textrm{Rational functions }X\dashrightarrow\mathbb P^1\}.$$
The functor $K(-)$ establishes a duality between the category of 
$$
k\textrm{-varieties, with dominant rational maps,}
$$
and the category of
$$
\textrm{function fields over }k.
$$
In particular, to a dominant rational map $f:X\dashrightarrow \mathbb P^1$ there corresponds a monomorphism $f^\ast: k(t)\to K(X)$. The image of $t$ under $f^\ast$ "is" the rational function $f$.